# vue-router next method not working always in beforeach

Tags: vue-router

i'm creating a navigation guard for redirect user to some page, 
i get auth status from vuex:

```
state: {
    auth: false,
},
```

and in vue-router beforeach, i set a condition that when auth state is false and route is not adminAuth,
redirect to adminAuth route

```
var auth = store.state.auth
if (!auth){
    if( to.name !== "adminAuth" ){
      next( { name: 'adminAuth' } )
    }
}
```

problem is when route changed first time, next() not working properly, but second time, working properly!
can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to intercept the navigation request using `beforeResolve` or `beforeEnter` because `beforeEach` is too soon and some attributes of the logic you want to use have not been processed yet, so it is possible on second navigation that some underlying logic appears resolved because the next request is accessing something set by the previous request.

```js
const router = new VueRouter({

  routes: { ... }

})

router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {

  if(!router.app.$store.state.auth && to.name !== 'adminAuth') {

   next( { name: 'adminAuth' } )

  }

  next()

})
```